# Letter combinations that sound the same

Tags: pronunciation, sounds

I'm interested to see what combinations of letters sound like each other - there are of course the obvious ones:

c --> k or s

-ory --> I (pronounced ee)

f --> ph

What other ones are out there? I'm interested to explore some of these (I'm not sure exactly what the technical term is). What can you think of?

Comment: Homophony, they are homophones.

Comment: Google how to pronounce the word *ghoti*  Although it is a joke, it shows how inconsistent English spelling is!